# Formulario PHP al adjuntar archivo lo convierte en .dat

Tags: php, html, formularios

Buenos dias,

Tengos dos problemillas he echo un formulario en php para que puedan adjuntar archivos y los envien al correo envie bien el correo pero el archivo lo llama asi: **Datos adjunto sin titulo 0066.dat**  dando igual el formato con que lo suba.

Otro error bueno mas que error es que no me sale es añadir al darle a enviar un mensaje de agradecimiento.
Os dejo el código:

```
<?php
 require("mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
 session_start();
$msg = "";
if ($_POST['action'] == "send") {


    $varname = $_FILES['subida']['name'];
    $vartemp = $_FILES['subida']['tmp_name'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->Host = "mail.hogarium.es";
    $mail->From = $_POST['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['Asunto'];
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['Recipiente']);
    if ($varname != "") {
        $mail->AddAttachment($vartemp, $varname);
    }
    $link = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $body = "<font face=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif size=2 color=#333333><strong>Datos de Informaci&oacute;n en Contacto:</strong></font><br><br><hr width=450px align=left><br><font face=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif size=2><strong>Nombre:</strong> ".$_POST['Nombre']."<br><strong>Apellidos:</strong> ".$_POST['apellidos']."<br><strong>Tel&eacute;fono:</strong> ".$_POST['telefono']."<br><strong>Correo Electr&oacute;nico:</strong> ".$_POST['email']."<br><strong>Mensaje:</strong> ".$_POST['message']."</font><p></p>";
$body.= "<p><font face=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif size=2>Mi Empresa<br><strong>slogan de la empresa</strong></font><br><i><a href='$link/' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333333; text-decoration:none;'>$link/</a></i></p>";

$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();

/*header("Location: $link/gracias.php");*/
exit;


 }

  ?>
```

AÑADO LO QUE HIZE NUEVO AÑADIENDO EL INDEX.HTML CON EL SCRIPT PHPMAILER a ver si tengo algun error por que sigue sin ir

```
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Envía tu curriculum</title>






    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Contact Form -->
    <div class="c-form-container section-container section-container-image-bg">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 c-form section-description wow fadeIn">
                    <h1>Trabaja con Nosotros <strong>Hogarium</strong></h1>
                    <p>Rellene este formulario para enviar tu información a nuestro departamento de R.R.H.H</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 c-form-box wow fadeInUp">

                    <div class="c-form-top">
                        <div class="c-form-top-left">
                            <h3>Formulario</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c-form-top-right">
                            <div class="c-form-top-right-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c-form-bottom">
                        <form role="form" action="assets/contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="Recipiente" value="webmaster@hogarium.es" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="Asunto" value="Curriculum" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-name">
                                    <span class="label-text">Nombre:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre..." class="c-form-name form-control" id="c-form-name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-apellidos">
                                    <span class="label-text">Apellidos:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Tu apellido..." class="c-form-apellidos form-control" id="c-form-apellidos" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-email">
                                    <span class="label-text">Email:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Dirección de email..." class="c-form-email form-control" id="c-form-email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-telefono">
                                    <span class="label-text">Teléfono:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono movil o fijo..." class="c-form-telefono form-control" id="c-form-telefono" required>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-perfil">
                                    <span class="label-text">Perfil Profesional:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <select name="perfil" class="c-form-perfil form-control" id="c-form-perfil"> 
                                <option>Encargado/Dependiente de Comercio</option>
                                <option>Administrativo/Aux Administrativo</option>
                                <option>Comercial</option>
                                <option>Conductor</option>
                                <option>Personal de Almacén</option>
                                <option>Operaciones/Logistica</option>
                                <option>Producción/Fabricación</option>
                                <option>Recursos Humanos</option>
                                <option>Atención al cliente</option>
                                <option>Diseñador Grafico</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-subida">
                                    <span class="label-text">Sube tu Curriculum:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="file" name="subida" value="30000" class="c-form-subida form-control" id="c-form-subida" required>
                            </div>
                           <!--- <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-subject">
                                    <span class="label-text">Asunto:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Ejemplo (Curriculum)..." class="c-form-subject form-control" id="c-form-subject">
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="c-form-message">
                                    <span class="label-text">¿Qué puedes aportar a nuestra empresa?:</span> 
                                    <span class="contact-error"></span>
                                </label>
                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Escriba aquí su texto..." class="c-form-message form-control" id="c-form-message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Enviar mi Curriculum</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!--
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 c-form-info-title wow fadeInUp">
                    <h3>...or find us here:</h3>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 c-form-info-box wow fadeInUp">
                    <div class="c-form-info-box-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p>Via Po 10<br>10136 Turin IT</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 c-form-info-box wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="c-form-info-box-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p>Phone:<br>333 12 68 347</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 c-form-info-box wow fadeInUp">
                    <div class="c-form-info-box-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p>Email:<br><a href="mailto:contact.azmind@gmail.com">contact.azmind@gmail.com</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 c-form-info-box wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="c-form-info-box-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p>Skype:<br>azmind_online</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            ---->
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</body>
```

Comment: 1. Imagino que el archivo adjunto no tiene la extensión `.dat`... Si no tiene extensión, el hecho de indicar esto: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` puede provocar que el archivo se convierta en extensión `.dat`. En cualquier caso, puedes probar esto: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`(ver [Content-Type en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). 2. Para tener una confirmación del mensaje enviado, sólo tiene que rodear la llamada a `mail` por un `if`.  Algo así: `if (  mail($emailTo, $subject... etc) ){echo "Enviado"; }else{echo "No enviado";}`

Comment: Probare tambien muchas gracias

Comment: Como se ha dicho en la respuesta, la librería PHPMailer funciona mejor, sobre todo si tienes que enviar archivos adjuntos. Y es muy simple de usar y configurar.

Comment: como opinion personal, planteate mejor **swiftMailer**. Casi todos los frameworks de php estan integrandola, y es mucho mas comoda que phpmailer

Comment: Buenas he añadido el index.html y el phpmailer y a ver si me podeis ayudar algo mas que no encuentro los fallos que nunca lo utilize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para enviar mails prueba con el siguiente script, te vas a ahorrar muchos quebraderos de cabeza y mucho código.

> PHPMailer http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: Gracias voy hacer la pruebas. Saludos ya comento a ver que tal

Comment: Buenas he modificado la pregunta he añadido el PHPmailer pero no se si lo tengo correcto le importaria darle un vistazo gracias

Comment: El PHP mailer es de PHP, no javascript. Te lo estaba planteando como alternativa al codigo que tienes tu.

Comment: ah vale perdon que torpe tienes razon

Comment: Buenas llevo dandole vueltas a esto y descargado ejemplos y tal que si me funcionan lo adapto a mi formulario que es plantilla de bootstrap y nada no hay manera :(

Comment: Actualiza tu código a ver.

Comment: ya lo tiene actualizado gracias